# Directive creating new directives with own scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope

I have a directive, which contains three buttons. If i hit one it should create a new instance of the directive with an own scope.

This new directive should get an title which is set to the parameter of the previous clicked button.

```
ng-click="add('blue');
```

So the directive has an isolated scope, set by:

```
scope: {},
restrict: 'E',
templateUrl: 'xyz.html'
```

And a link inside DDO:

```
controller: function($scope) {
  $scope.colorTypes = {
    "red" : true,
    "green" : false,
    "blue" : false
  }
}
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
  scope.add = function(color){
    colorTypes = {
      "red": false,
      "green": false,
      "blue": false
    }
    colorTypes[color] = true;
    var el = $compile('<my-directive myColor='colorTypes'></my-directive>')(scope);
    element.parent().append(el);
  }
}
```

How can i get the value (new color) into the $compile for the new directive?

Comment: which value are you talking about? `color` to be set as an attribute of `<my-directive>`?

Comment: just edited the last lines ;)

Comment: what is `myColor` then?

Comment: like you said color, should become a new attribute for the directive, so i can highlight the button, which was clicked on the previous directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing almost everything correctly, except passing the value :)

You can either do string manipulation before to add the actual string of the `color` variable.

Or (I think, more elegantly), you could just create an element and add an attribute:

```
link: function(scope, element) {
  scope.add = function(colorType) {
    var colorTypes = {
      "green": false,
      "red": false,
      "blue": false
    };
    colorTypes[colorType] = true;

    var newElem = angular.element("<my-colors>");

    var childScope = scope.$new(false); // create a child scope for the directive
    childScope.colorTypes = colorTypes;

    $compile(newElem)(childScope);

    element.parent().append(newElem);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to better describe the `<my-directive>` (does it use isolate scope? why does it need a child scope?) and also the parent directive with the buttons - how are these buttons created and where does the object you want to pass come from

Comment: buttons are create via ng-repeat setting key to >name< and highlight state by ng-class if true.

Comment: @SvenKoluem, I really think you should edit the original question and add the details of exactly what `<my-directive>` does/expects regardless of how it is created. A plunker would help. At this point, I don't fully understand your issue.

Comment: You could always set `childScope.myColors = {...}` - if that helps. This would expose a new color-configuration object to the new instance of `<my-directive>`

Comment: The edit doesn't correspond to the original question :) In the question, you have "red", "green", "blue". In the edit you have "and", "or"...

Comment: Edited question. Still dont get it, why the "§$% the new directive get the controller values, not the one we directly set on the new scope.

Comment: @SvenKoluem, not sure what you mean. It seems to be working: http://plnkr.co/edit/aHwmA8sEwthNbQjxo4Gy?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly about your desired endpoint, but this shows how to use the value:

```
scope: {
     myColor: "="
},
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.addDirective = function(color){
         var el = $compile('<my-directive myColor=\'{{color}}\'></my-directive>')(scope);
         element.parent().append(el);
      }
}
```

Notice you must have the `myColor` in scope since the directive is expecting it.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11127/)